# The image size is not the same after rotation in mobile IOS device

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I am making a website and viewing it on my iPad's safari browser.

In Portrait orientation the site looks fine. But when the device rotates, the size of the web page(its width and height) is different.

It seems that the landscape view is about 1.3 times the size of the portrait.

How do I make the size the same in both orientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be this could help:

```
var w = $('img').width();
var h = $('img').height();

$(window).orientationchange(function(e) {
     $('img').css({'width':w, 'height':h});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just give width to image in pixels.

Comment: I tried assign width height inside $(window).orientationchange(function(e) {....}); However, it doesn't make any different, the weird is I tried to alert the width , the case of potarit or landscape are same (but it is not if from my observe).

Answer (score 1):

Two options only.

1. Incldue "viewport" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
2. Use media query
   http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
   You can adjust whatever you want for your CSS according to different sizes with media query used.